# Extract specific format text from file -perl

Tags: perl

**file1**

```
--- abcd10 ---

--- abcd31 ---

--- abcd32 ---
MY Addr           info  name policy
---------------------------------------------------------
00:0a:91:00:65:93 HQLT DKAHN   Default


--- abcd33 ---
No info found

--- abcd34 ---
No info found

--- abcd35 ---

MY Addr           info  name policy
---------------------------------------------------------
00-0a-91-00:15:03 HQ-LT-DKAHN   Default
00-0a-91-10:15:03 HQ-LT-DKAHN   Default
```

in the above file I want to extract only specific format.

```
--- abcd32 ---
MY Addr           info  name policy
---------------------------------------------------------
00:0a:91:00:65:93 HQLT DKAHN   Default
```

And

```
--- abcd35 ---
MY Addr           info  name policy
---------------------------------------------------------
00-0a-91-00:15:03 HQ-LT-DKAHN   Default
00-0a-91-10:15:03 HQ-LT-DKAHN   Default
```

**Code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl  
use warnings; 
use strict;
my $file;
my $start_marker_mqstats = qr{^\-+\s*\w+\s*\-+.* $}x;
my $end_marker_mqstats = qr{^\s* $}x; 
open($file,"<", "file") || die $!; 
while(<$file>) {       
  if ($_ =~/^\-\-\-\s\w+\s\-\-\-/){   
         if ($_ =~/^MY\sAddr.*/){       
            next unless my $range = /$start_marker_mqstats/ .. /$end_marker_mqstats/; 
            my $line = $_;
            print $line if $range !~ /^1$|E/;    
        }     
     }
 }
```

Comment: #!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
my $file;
my $start_marker_mqstats = qr{^\-+\s*\w+\s*\-+.* $}x;
my $end_marker_mqstats = qr{^\s* $}x;

open($file,"<", "file") || die $!;
while(<$file>) {
        if ($_ =~/^\-\-\-\s\w+\s\-\-\-/){
             if ($_ =~/^MY\sAddr.*/){
               next unless my $range = /$start_marker_mqstats/ .. /$end_marker_mqstats/;
               my $line = $_;
               print $line if $range !~ /^1$|E/;
           }
         }
}

Comment: My above code does not work

Comment: I want to print/extract like below.


--- abcd32 ---
MY Addr info name policy
-----------------------------------------------
00:0a:91:00:65:93 HQLT DKAHN Default

-- abcd35 ---
MY Addr info name policy
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
00-0a-91-00:15:03 HQ-LT-DKAHN Default 00-0a-91-10:15:03 HQ-LT-DKAHN Default

Answer (score 1):

You can use paragraph mode (setting `$/ = ""`) and "grep" for lines starting with `MY`, using the `/m` regex modifier to make newline match `^`.

```
perl -00 -nlwe"print if /^MY /m" input.txt
```

`-00` sets the input record separator `$/` to `""`.

Or as a program file:

```
$/ = "";

while (<>) {
    print if /^MY /m;
}
```

In both cases, output is:

```
--- abcd32 ---
MY Addr           info  name policy
---------------------------------------------------------
00:0a:91:00:65:93 HQLT DKAHN   Default

MY Addr           info  name policy
---------------------------------------------------------
00-0a-91-00:15:03 HQ-LT-DKAHN   Default
00-0a-91-10:15:03 HQ-LT-DKAHN   Default
```

The missing header in the second case is because you had an empty line there in your sample input. I am guessing that was a copy/paste error on your part, and not how it is in your input.

Comment: Thanks TLP. Can I do like this? A line contained or has --- abcdxx --- and next line start with MY then it should print from --- abcdxx --- till next empty line or the word match.
--- abcdxx ---
MY Addr           info  name policy
---------------------------------------------------------
00:0a:91:00:65:93 HQLT DKAHN   Default

--- abcdxx ---
MY Addr           info  name policy
---------------------------------------------------------
00-0a-91-00:15:03 HQ-LT-DKAHN   Default
00-0a-91-10:15:03 HQ-LT-DKAHN   Default

Comment: Not quite sure I understand your meaning. Are you asking me the same question again, after I answered it?